# Is topic coherence (gensim CoherenceModel) calculated based exclusively on my corpus or external data as well?

Tags: data-science, topic-modeling

I'm topic modeling a corpus of English 20th century correspondence using LDA and I've been using **topic coherence** (as well as silhouette scores) to evaluate my topics. I use gensim's `CoherenceModel` with `c_v` coherence and the highest I've ever gotten was a `0.35` score in all the models I've tested, even in the topics that make the most sense to me in qualitative evaluation, even after extensive pre-processing and hyperparameter comparison.

So I basically accepted that that's the best I'd get, but in order to write about it now I've been reading up on topic coherence and I've understood it's a pipeline and it models human judgement. One thing I can't seen to find clear info on, though: Is it based exclusively on calculations made on **my** corpus, or is it based on some external data as well? Like trained on external corpora that might have nothing to do with my domain? Should I use `u_mass` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, except `u_mass`, they all use external reference datasets. However, it may not be a bad thing, as those reference datasets provide richer information.

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide any reference sources?

Comment: Section 2 in [this paper](http://svn.aksw.org/papers/2015/WSDM_Topic_Evaluation/public.pdf).